# Return Select Statement as Rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sqlplus

I am not sure if I am mis-remembering or if it was a different SQL format, but I am sure I had a way to switch the way the results are displayed in Oracle. I am trying to query a table with multiple columns to be used to compare after an update. The select statement makes the output look a mess even after using spool/linesize etc.

Anyway I am sure there was a command I can enter that transposes the results to return something like this

```
ID: 1
Name: Bob
Surname: Jenkins

ID: 2
Name: Dave
Surname: Hedgehog.

Etc...
```

I can't find it anywhere so not sure if it was a different SQL format other than Oracle I used it on.

Edit: I am using a Putty connection into a server then logging in with SQLPLUS

Comment: Which SQL query environment/tool are you using?

Comment: Putty - I will add that to my original question sorry

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there's no *built-in* SQL*Plus capability to do that.

There's the `PRINT_TABLE` procedure you can use for that purpose.

I sincerely apologize to the original author; I don't know / remember who it was, and procedure itself doesn't reveal that information.

```
create or replace procedure print_table (p_query in varchar2)   
   authid current_user
is
   l_thecursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
   l_columnvalue   varchar2 (4000);
   l_status        integer;
   l_desctbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;
   l_colcnt        number;
begin
   execute immediate 'alter session set 
        nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';

   dbms_sql.parse (l_thecursor, p_query, dbms_sql.native);
   dbms_sql.describe_columns (l_thecursor, l_colcnt, l_desctbl);

   for i in 1 .. l_colcnt
   loop
      dbms_sql.define_column (l_thecursor,
                              i,
                              l_columnvalue,
                              4000);
   end loop;

   l_status := dbms_sql.execute (l_thecursor);

   while (dbms_sql.fetch_rows (l_thecursor) > 0)
   loop
      for i in 1 .. l_colcnt
      loop
         dbms_sql.column_value (l_thecursor, i, l_columnvalue);
         dbms_output.
          put_line (
            rpad (l_desctbl (i).col_name, 30) || ': ' || l_columnvalue);
      end loop;

      dbms_output.put_line ('-----------------');
   end loop;

   execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-rr'' ';
exception
   when others
   then
      execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-rr'' ';

      raise;
end;
/
```

By default:

```
SQL> select * from dept where deptno <= 20;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
```

With `print_table`:

```
SQL> exec print_table('select * from dept where deptno <= 20');
DEPTNO                        : 10
DNAME                         : ACCOUNTING
LOC                           : NEW YORK
-----------------
DEPTNO                        : 20
DNAME                         : RESEARCH
LOC                           : DALLAS
-----------------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Don't forget to `set serveroutput on`.

Comment: Procedure print_table is from asktom site [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958).

Comment: Thank you, @Ponder. I included link into my copy of that procedure, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you're thinking of the "UNPIVOT" operation in Oracle SQL, which can be used to transpose columns and rows in a table. Here's an example:

Suppose you have a table called "mytable" with the following data:

ID  Name    Surname
1   Bob Jenkins
2   Dave    Hedgehog
3   Charlie Donkey
To transpose the columns and rows, you can use the UNPIVOT operation like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (AttributeValue FOR AttributeName IN (Name, Surname));
```

This will produce the following output:

| ID | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Bob |
| 1 | Surname | Jenkins |
| 2 | Name | Dave |
| 2 | Surname | Hedgehog |
| 3 | Name | Charlie |
| 3 | Surname | Donkey |

This output lists each attribute name and value as a separate row, with the corresponding ID. You can then use this output to compare values after an update.

Note that the UNPIVOT operation is not specific to Oracle SQL, but it is a standard SQL operation supported by many database systems.