# How to convert single record as vertical rows | SQL |

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table with data in it.

employee : NAME , AGE , SALARY , DESIGNATION, COURSE , JOIN_DATE

```
A,24,2400,Sr,Developer,10-JUN-23  
B,24,2400,Jr,Developer,10-JUN-23
C,24,2400,Tr,Developer,10-JUN-23
D,24,2400,Sr,Developer,10-JUN-23
```

I have written a query to fetch only one record

```
select * from employee where NAME='A';
```

Now I want that all details of his into other table as vericatl data (Inserting)

Table : Student_A -> column ->  DETAILS  varchar2(4000)

```
DETAILS 
A
24
2400
Sr
Developer
10-JUN-23
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75754482/return-select-statement-as-rows/75754617#75754617

Comment: Never store age. People turn older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store DOB instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all the column values to strings and then `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT details
FROM   ( SELECT name,
                TO_CHAR(age) AS age,
                TO_CHAR(salary) AS salary,
                designation,
                course,
                TO_CHAR(join_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS join_date
         FROM   employee
         WHERE  name = 'A')
       UNPIVOT(
         details
         FOR type IN (NAME, AGE, SALARY, DESIGNATION, COURSE, JOIN_DATE)
       );
```

Which, for your sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (NAME, AGE, SALARY, DESIGNATION, COURSE, JOIN_DATE) AS
SELECT 'A',24,2400,'Sr','Developer', DATE '2023-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',24,2400,'Jr','Developer', DATE '2023-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',24,2400,'Tr','Developer', DATE '2023-06-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D',24,2400,'Sr','Developer', DATE '2023-06-10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DETAILS |
| --- |
| A |
| 24 |
| 2400 |
| Sr |
| Developer |
| 2023-06-10 00:00:00 |

If you want to insert into another table then use `INSERT INTO table_name (columns) SELECT ...`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CEmXzjUb)

Comment: -> Column names might vary it might be more as well not passing as static

Comment: @memotib827 In SQL, the column names must be known before the query. If you are using PL/SQL and dynamic SQL then you will need to work out what the column names are first. This may be something that is better done in a third-party language (i.e. Java, C#, PHP, etc.) as it will be much easier to work with dynamic columns and transposing the data in that than it will in SQL or PL/SQL.